# Chrome bug when maximizing

Tags: gnome, google-chrome

I'm running Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.  When I maximize Chrome it fills the screen except the right and bottom sides are invisible and the desktop shows through.  You can see other windows behind it, but the buttons on the invisible maximized chrome are still active.  If you drag the title bar down to un-maximize (or use the invisible buttons) the window returns to it's shape and is completely visible.

[image: invisible chrome bug]

Here's another shot of the maximized window in expose mode showing the entire graphical bug.  Notice that the window selector shows the right and bottom sides as transparent.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't found a complete solution.  But I dug up an [old bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=26598) for Chromium (the opensource version of Chrome) regarding the exact same issue.

One of the commenters posted a workaround:

> It means that the WM is somehow failing to resize the window properly. We've had this 
>   kind of problem before, but I couldn't find the bug for it. **As a workaround, you could 
>   try enabling the system titlebar (right click on empty part of tab strip).**

This works for now.